# How can I get my shower tiles really clean?

Tags: cleaning, shower, tile

My shower tiles in my apartment are kind of nasty, and I've tried spraying them with Clorox Bleach Foamer and also Tilex:Mold & Mildew and then scrubbing with a magic eraser thing.  I can try scrubbing longer/harder, but are there any tricks or techniques to make these shower tiles really clean?  (Notice the sort of stained tiles in the picture.)

*Click photo for full size*

[image]

Comment: Looks kind of like rust to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The staining looks like it is from water damage. My guess is it is behind the glaze that coats the face of the tile.  Unfortunetly there is no way to repair this type of damage short of replacing the tile. I have typically seen this on tiles that were cut and improperly grouted. Sealing the grout may prevent it from getting worse or showing up on other tiles.

Answer (score 1):

If you scrape a small areas with something like a razor blade, does it appear that its ont he surface? If so, you might try an oxygen bleach like [StainSolver](http://www.stainsolver.com/).